# Accessing caller ID data via API

Tags: api, phone, tracking

I am helping local businesses get back on track by building small, *free* software tools that can help them with their operation.

A local barber shop owner is asking me if there is a way for them to store client contact info based on caller id data. They want to be able to reach their clients in case of another lockdown, confirm appointments and add small notes such as haircut style preference, preferred barber etc.

Can anyone recommend a reliable and inexpensive caller id with an API I can use to access the call logs? The owner also requested that they keep their current phone number because there is no way to notify clients of a phone number change.

I looked into platforms like Twilio, CallRail and PhoneWagon since I have used them before on commercial projects, but they all seem like an overkill for a simple caller id log.

Answer (score 1):

In an effort to cut down on spam callers, I built a phone blocker from a Raspberry Pi.  I used some Open Source software called [NCID](http://ncid.sourceforge.net/).  It runs under several platforms and provides a caller log.  I used the caller log to determine what callers I needed to block.  The log contained the caller “name” and phone number.  The software provides several packages and is worth a look.